# Error in creating a new columns in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

[image]

Tried creating a new column to categorize different time frames into categories using np.select. However, python throws an error saying shape mismatch. I'm not sure how to get it corrected.

Comment: Please paste and format your code. See [ask] and [example]. Also [tour] and [help] for orientation

Answer (score 0):

For your logic, it's simple to use `hour` attribute of *datetime*

```
import numpy as np
s = pd.Series(pd.date_range("1-Apr-2021", "now", freq="4H"), name="start_date")
(s.to_frame()
 .join(pd.Series(np.select([s.dt.hour.between(1,6),
                            s.dt.hour.between(7,12)],
                           [1,2],0), name="cat"))
 .head(8)
)
```

|  | start_date | cat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2021-04-01 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 1 | 2021-04-01 04:00:00 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-04-01 08:00:00 | 2 |
| 3 | 2021-04-01 12:00:00 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-04-01 16:00:00 | 0 |
| 5 | 2021-04-01 20:00:00 | 0 |
| 6 | 2021-04-02 00:00:00 | 0 |
| 7 | 2021-04-02 04:00:00 | 1 |